# Filter file based on internal value within a column

Tags: unix

In UNIX, I would like to filter my 3 columns file based on the "DP" values that within the 3rd column.
I'd like to obtain only rows that have DP values higher than 7.

```
A|49.14|AC=2;AF=0.500;AN=4;BaseQRankSum=1.380;DP=6;Dels=0.00;
T|290.92|AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=8;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;
T|294.75|AC=6;AF=1.00;AN=6;DP=9;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;MLEAC=6;
```

I'm using here "|" for separating between my three columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one simple solution

```
$ echo "A|49.14|AC=2;AF=0.500;AN=4;BaseQRankSum=1.380;DP=6;Dels=0.00;
AC=6;AF=1.00;AN=6;DP=9;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;MLEAC=6;T|290.92|AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=8;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;
MLEAC=6;" \
| awk '{dpVal=$0;sub(/.*DP=/, "", dpVal);sub(/;.*$/,"", dpVal); if (dpVal>7) print}'
```

**output**

```
T|290.92|AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=8;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;
T|294.75|AC=6;AF=1.00;AN=6;DP=9;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;MLEAC=6;
```

This makes a copy of each line ($0), the strips away everything before `DP=`, and everything after the trailing `;` char for that field, leaving just the value for DP. That value is tested, and if true the whole line is printed (the default action of awk `print` is to print the whole line, but you can tell it to print anything you like, maybe `print "Found it:" $0` or zillons of variants.

**edit**

> I would like to keep all the first 53 lines intact and save them as well to my Output.txt file.

Yes, very easy, you're on the right track. With awk is is very easy to have multiple conditions process different parts or conditions in a file. Try this:

```
awk 'FNR <= 53 {print}
     FNR >  53 {
        vpVal=$0;sub(/.*DP=/, "", dpVal);sub(/;.*$/,"", dpVal)
        if (dpVal>7) print
    }'  File.vcf > Output.txt
```

(i don't have a file to test with, so let me know if this isn't right).

IHTH

Comment: Thanks, it works great - but I would need to add to it another level: The command I'm currently using is:  awk 'FNR > 53' File.vcf |awk '{dpVal=$0;sub(/.*DP=/, "", dpVal);sub(/;.*$/,"", dpVal);if(dpVal>=6) print}' > Output.txt  As you can see I'm running the filter from line 54 onward. I would like to keep all the first 53 lines intact and save them as well to my Output.txt file. Can I use one command liner to do so?

Comment: I tried: awk 'FNR <= 55 {print} ; FNR >  55 { vpVal=$0;sub(/.*DP=/, "", dpVal);sub(/;.*$/,"", dpVal); if (dpVal>=6) print }'  threePatients.vcf > Output.txt  However, while there is no error message - I only get the first part to work, meaning - I just get the 55 header lines in my Output.txt file, the rest of the command doesn't seem to function. 
I have managed to solve my task using one command line like this: (head -n 55 threePatients.vcf && awk 'FNR > 55' threePatients.vcf |awk '{dpVal=$0;sub(/.*DP=/, "", dpVal);sub(/;.*$/,"", dpVal);if(dpVal>=6) print}') > threePatients.MinimalDP6.vcf

Comment: I am very interested however to learn/see if your suggestion could be further improved, so it would actually consider the two partsm and not just the first, as currently it does... If you could, please have a second look and tell me if you have any suggestion. Your command, if works, looks more elegant than mine. Thanks! (I could email you the VCF file if you want!)